# Return value of a function using switch case without break

Tags: c, switch-statement, return-value

```
int pr(char elem) /* Function for precedence */
{
    switch (elem)
    {
        case '#': return 0;
        case '(': return 1;
        case '+':
        case '-': return 2;
        case '*': 
        case '/':
        case '%': return 3;
        case '^': return 4;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me **what** will be the return value of the function if the `elem` entered is either **' + '**  or  **' * '**?

And also **why** that will be the return value.

Comment: `break` is missing in every case statement.

Comment: Character literals (`'*'`,`'^'`, `'#'`, ...) are of type `int` and have a possibility to be out of range for a `char`. You cause UB when no `case` is meet.

Answer (score 0):

Cases in a `switch` statement can *fall through* to the next case.

So if `elem` is `+`, it falls through to the `-` case and 2 is returned.  Similarly, if `elem` is `*` or `/` it falls through to the `%` case and 3 is returned.

Note also that if none of the cases match then a `return` statement will *not* be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `break` or `return` after `case '+':` and `case '*':` statements, the program will continue till the control sees a `break` or `return` or end of the block `}`

so the output will be

```
+ = 2
* = 3
```

for the below program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pr(char elem);

int main()
{
    printf("+ = %d\n", pr('+'));
    printf("* = %d\n", pr('*'));
    
    return 0;
}

int pr(char elem) /* Function for precedence */
{
    switch (elem)
    {
        case '#': return 0;
        case '(': return 1;
        case '+':
        case '-': return 2;
        case '*': 
        case '/':
        case '%': return 3;
        case '^': return 4;
    }
}
```

Note that any or all of `pr('*');` , `pr('/');` or `pr('%')` will return `3`
since there is a `return` only after `%`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation!